# How to build pgloader on Windows (or CentOS7)?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, centos7, pgloader

I need to convert some MySQL databases to Postgresql.

I came across the [pgloader](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader) script, which promises to be the best solution, but coming from a Windows environment I have *no idea* how to build it.
My server has CentOS7, but I have never compiled anything myself on it, other than with `yum`. I just don't know where to start or even how to run the bootstrap-centos7.sh script, which is mentioned in the readme-file.

Did anyone ever compile pgloader on Windows or can provide some clear steps how to build this program on CentOS7 ?

Comment: If anyone reaches this post nowaday, documentation is here https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader

Answer (score 4):

perhaps you already installed this, but for other people it should be easy:

```
sudo yum install -y git
git clone https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader.git
cd pgloader
chmod +x ./bootstrap-centos7.sh
sudo ./bootstrap-centos7.sh
make pgloader
```

after make you can check if pgloader is working by exexuting command `./build/bin/pgloader --help` (from pgloader directory)

Comment: but this answer is just for centOS. Where is the part for windows?

Comment: is there no documentation about pgloader for windows? wtf?

Comment: nevermind I am just downloading CentOS for testing purpose in a VM ;)

Comment: try to create issue on [github](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader) or try to contact dimitri dim@tapoueh.org

Answer (score 0):

In reference to bilak's answer I have tested his solution and saw some errors and it it still not functional yet.

Following changes needed to be done from my side:

1. sudo 'yum install -y git' instead of sudo yum install -y git
2. for the clone step I had to use git:// instead of https://

The other things are the same for me. But as soon as I want to execute the `./bootstrap-centos7.sh` I am getting a bunch of error for unavailable servers and stuff.

I will create an issue on this via Github and keep this answer updated...